How to Determine the Expected Number of Flips in a Biased Random Walk with Reflecting and Absorbing Barriers?
I'm working on a problem involving a biased random walk captured by the following rules:

Starting from 0 points, you flip a biased coin with probability  of heads.
On heads: You move up by 1 point.
On tails: You move down by 1 point unless you’re already at 0, in which case you stay at 0 (a reflecting barrier).
The process ends when you reach a specified target  points (an absorbing barrier).

My goal is to determine the expected number of flips required to reach N for some w.
My research thus far has lead me to believe that this can be modeled via a recurrence relation, but I candidly have no idea on how to approach it.
More than just an answer to the general case, I would love to be able to understand how to approach this problem

Yes, you're correct that the expected number $\ f_i\ $ of flips required to reach $\ N\ $ points from a current total of $\ i\ $ can be obtained from a recurrence relation.  In fact, it's exactly the same recurrence relation
$$
f_i=1+wf_{i+1}+(1-w)f_{i-1}\label{1}\tag{1}
$$
governing the expected time to termination in the gambler's ruin problem.  The only difference between your problem and the one treated on the page at the above-cited link is the boundary condition for the barrier at $0$.  In the gambler's ruin problem, with an absorbing barrier there, you have $\ f_0=0\ ,$ whereas in your problem with a reflecting barrier there, you have
$$
f_0=1+wf_1+(1-w)f_0\ ,
$$
or, equivalently,
$$
f_0=f_1+\frac{1}{w}\ .\label{2}\tag{2}
$$
The boundary condition at the other barrier is the same for both problems:
$$
f_N=0\ .\label{3}\tag{3}
$$
The general solution to the recurrence \eqref{1}is
$$
f_i=\cases{-\frac{i}{2w}+A+B\left(\frac{1-w}{w}\right)^i&if $\ w<\frac{1}{2}$\\
A+Bi-i^2&if $\ w=\frac{1}{2}$\\
-\frac{i}{2w}+A+B\left(\frac{w-1}{w}\right)^i&if $\ w>\frac{1}{2}$}
$$
for some constants $\ A\ $ and $\ B\ .$ The boundary conditions \eqref{2} and \eqref{3} give you two linear equations for the constants $\ A\ $ and $\ B\ ,$  which you can solve to find their values as functions of $\ w\ $ and $\ N\ .$

For $\ w<\frac{1}{2}\ ,$\begin{align}&f_i=\\&\frac{N-i}{2w}+\frac{1}{2(2w-1)}\left(\left(\frac{1-w}{w}\right)^i-\left(\frac{1-w}{w}\right)^N\right)\\f_0&=\\&\frac{N}{2w}+\frac{1}{2(2w-1)}\left(1-\left(\frac{1-w}{w}\right)^N\right)\ .\end{align}For $\ w=\frac{1}{2}\ ,$\begin{align}f_i&=N+N^2-i-i^2\\f_0&=N+N^2\end{align}For $\ w>\frac{1}{2}\ ,$\begin{align}&f_i=\\&\frac{N-i}{2w}+\frac{1}{2}\left(\left(\frac{w-1}{w}\right)^i-\left(\frac{w-1}{w}\right)^N\right)\\f_0&=\\&\frac{N}{2w}+\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\left(\frac{w-1}{w}\right)^N\right)\ .\end{align}


There ought to be a mistake with the solutions? I am getting negative values where reasonable numbers are expected. For example, when $N = 1, w = 1/3$, the expected value is $3$, but trying the above equations both $f_0$ and $f_i$ are producing incorrect (negative results). In general, when $N = 1$ the solution is always $1/w$.

When simplifying the expression $f_0$ with $N = 1$, I get $\frac{w}{(1 - w) (2 w - 1)} \neq 1/w$

Yes, I obviously made some arithmetical errors in calculating the solution of the recursion originally given in the answer.  I've redone the calculations  and obtained the solution now given in the updated answer.  This does now give the correct results for the parameter values you list in your comments.  Thank you for picking  up the error.

Let $T_n$ be the expected number of flips needed to reach state $N$ from state $n$. Set up the system of equations
$$
\begin{align*}
T_0 &= 1 + (1 - w) T_0 + w T_1 \\
T_1 &= 1 + (1 - w) T_0 + w T_2 \\
&\vdots \\
T_{N - 1} &= 1 + (1 - w) T_{N -2}
\end{align*}
$$
and solve for $T_0$.
